# Ember data delete nested records

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

I have multiple shopping carts.
Every cart has multiple products.

When I trie to remove a product from a cart, generated url tries to remove a product globally not just from that specific cart.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find("cart", 2);
  },
  actions: {
    remove: function(product){
      product.deleteRecord();
      product.save();
    }
  }
});

{{#each product in model.products}}
    <div>{{product.title}} <button {{action "remove" product}}>x</button></div>
  {{/each}}
```

HTTP request generated is DELETE products/{id}

I would expect it to somehow include cart id in url. How to handle such situations ?

demo: http://jsbin.com/lecejejara/1/edit?html,js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `deleteRecord()` which deletes the record, thus removing it globally. What you really need to do is disassociate the product and the shopping cart.

Assuming that in your scope your cart is called `cart`, you can change the template to also pass the cart:

```
{{#each product in model.products}}
    <div>{{product.title}} <button {{action "remove" product cart}}>x</button></div>
{{/each}}
```

and modify your remove action to disassociate this particular cart and the product:

```
  actions: {
    remove: function(product, cart){
      cart.get('products').removeObject(product);
      cart.save();
    }
  }
```

Comment: That way, when I want to delete a record I have to send the whole cart to server. Any ideas how to send only one item wanted to be deleted to increase performance ?